Terraform Azure Key Vault Access Policy Create/Destroy Loop
Anyone ever run into an issue with terraform and azure key vault access policy?  I have an issue where the key vault gets created with a module that sets some default access policies on the key vault.  Then when I create another resource that needs to set the system assigned identity access to the key vault, like synapse for example.  Terraform will add the azurerm_key_vault_access_policy once the resource is created, however, this will work on the first apply, after that the key vault module and azurerm_key_vault_access_policy will be in a destroy/recreate loop each time I plan depending on which was applied last.
If I remove the access policy from the key vault module, terraform will error stating the terraform principal doesn't have access to add policies, it looks to run a GET on the key vault to check if it is already there is my best guess. One of my default access policies in the module is to add the service principal used by terraform to the KV access policy, but then this starts the cycle again.  Wondering if this is a known issue, or how to rectify the key vault access policies for when resources get created with system assigned identities and then need added to the key vault access policies.
synapse.tf
# Key vault Policy 
import {
  to = azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.synapse-identity-policy
  id = module.app3-kv.vault_id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "synapse-identity-policy" {
  key_vault_id = module.app3-kv.vault_id
  tenant_id    = azurerm_synapse_workspace.synapse.identity[0].tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_synapse_workspace.synapse.identity[0].principal_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Get", "WrapKey", "UnwrapKey"
  ]

}

module - keyvault (main.tf)
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  name                       = var.kv_name
  location                   = var.location
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = var.kv_sku_name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption     = var.enabled_for_disk_encryption
  enabled_for_deployment          = var.enabled_for_deployment
  enabled_for_template_deployment = var.enabled_for_template_deployment
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  purge_protection_enabled   = true
  tags                       = var.tags

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = var.kv_access_group_id

    key_permissions         = var.key_permissions
    secret_permissions      = var.secret_permissions
    certificate_permissions = var.certificate_permissions
  } 
  
  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions         = var.key_permissions
    secret_permissions      = var.secret_permissions
    certificate_permissions = var.certificate_permissions
  } 

  //public_network_access_enabled = var.public_network_access_enabled
  network_acls {
    bypass         = var.kv_bypass
    default_action = var.kv_default_action
    ip_rules       = var.kv_ip_address
  }
  
}

output "vault_id" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id  
}

output "vault_name" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.name
}

output "vault_resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.resource_group_name
}

key_vault.tf
module "app3-kv" {
  source = "../modules/key_vault"

  kv_name                         = var.kv_name
  resource_group_name             = data.azurerm_resource_group.kv-rg.name
  location                        = var.location
  enabled_for_deployment          = true
  enabled_for_disk_encryption     = true
  enabled_for_template_deployment = true
  tags                            = var.kv_tags

  depends_on = [data.azurerm_resource_group.kv-rg]

}

plan where it removes the synapse identity after it has been applied.
# module.spexs-app3-kv.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
      ~ access_policy                   = [
            # (1 unchanged element hidden)
            {
                application_id          = ""
                certificate_permissions = [
                    "Get",
                    "List",
                    "GetIssuers",
                    "ListIssuers",
                ]
                key_permissions         = [
                    "Get",
                    "Create",
                    "Delete",
                    "List",
                    "Recover",
                    "Restore",
                    "UnwrapKey",
                    "WrapKey",
                    "List",
                    "GetRotationPolicy",
                    "SetRotationPolicy",
                ]
                object_id               = "964c5f8c-c077-44b0-8be4-60c775720e5e"
                secret_permissions      = [
                    "Get",
                    "List",
                    "Set",
                    "Delete",
                    "Recover",
                    "Restore",
                ]
                storage_permissions     = []
                tenant_id               = ""
            },
          - {
              - application_id          = ""
              - certificate_permissions = []
              - key_permissions         = [
                  - "Get",
                  - "WrapKey",
                  - "UnwrapKey",
                ]
              - object_id               = "b5957f89-c575-42f5-8fe1-c4ba8265eaa6"
              - secret_permissions      = []
              - storage_permissions     = []
              - tenant_id               = ""
            },
        ]
        id                              = "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/AGV-C-AKV-RGP-04-001/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/AGV-C-AKV-04-003-SYNAPSE"
        name                            = "AGV-C-AKV-04-003-SYNAPSE"
        tags                            = {
            "Billing Project" = ""
            "Component"       = "Azure Key Vault"
            "Environment"     = ""
            "System"          = ""
            "Terraform"       = ""
        }
        # (12 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }


From azurerm_key_vault_access_policy's documentation (emphasis mine):

It's possible to define Key Vault Access Policies both within the azurerm_key_vault resource via the access_policy block and by using the azurerm_key_vault_access_policy resource. However it's not possible to use both methods to manage Access Policies within a KeyVault, since there'll be conflicts.

I'm not sure if this is the case, given that the access policies are defined in different modules (if I understood correctly).
But anyway, try using a azurerm_key_vault_access_policy resource instead of an access_policy block in the keyvault module.
Something like:
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "p01" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = var.kv_access_group_id

  key_permissions         = var.key_permissions
  secret_permissions      = var.secret_permissions
  certificate_permissions = var.certificate_permissions
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "p02" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  key_permissions         = var.key_permissions
  secret_permissions      = var.secret_permissions
  certificate_permissions = var.certificate_permissions
}


Thank you!  I've ended up doing exactly this!
